# Populate spinner from arraylist in separate fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I have an app with 3 tabs. There's a main activity, and a fragment for each tab.

In fragment 1 (the first tab) I am able to add/remove items from a list view (stored in an arraylist). In fragment 2 (the second tab) I want to populate a spinner from the arraylist in the first tab; however I notice that I am unable to access objects from separate fragments (whether private, protected, or public).

What's the best way to pass the arraylist between fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment-to-fragment communication should go through the hosting Activity. Pass data up to the Activity from fragment1 (probably via a custom interface, to allow easy re-use of the Fragment), and then from the Activity into fragment2. See [this section of the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for more details:

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Comment: the example has helped me pass the object from fragment 1 to the activity, but unhelpful in passing the object from the activity to fragment 2. If I'm understanding correctly it seems to suggest creating a new fragment 2 each time fragment 1 is updated which seems very inefficient instead of finding a way to just update the object needing to be passed.

Comment: @glcohen creating a new fragment should not be necessary. See this quote from that page: "The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the Fragment instance with `findFragmentById()`, then directly call the fragment's public methods."